# Bash: Find directories with trailing spaces at the end of each name

Tags: bash

I am a complete newbie to Linux (I am using Linux Mint) and I need your help understanding basic bash commands.

I store my files on an external hard drive (NTFS formatting) that I use in different OS. My files are organized in many  directories (folders) and inside each primary directory I have more folders and inside those folders I have other folders and so on. I need a bash command to find all the **directories** with trailing spaces at the end of each name. If possible, I would also like to use a bash command to remove the blank space(s). I have tried looking into other answers but I only find the commands and no clear explanation of what they do, so I am not sure whether that is what I am looking for and I don’t want to risk changing something inadvertently. Any help explaining which commands to use would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following is written to be easy-to-follow (as a secondary goal), and correct in corner cases (as a primary goal):

```
# because "find"'s usage is dense, we're defining that command in an array, so each
# ...element of that array can have its usage described.
find_cmd=(
  find                 # run the tool 'find'
  .                    # searching from the current directory
  -depth               # depth-first traversal so we don't invalidate our own renames
  -type d              # including only directories in results
  -name '*[[:space:]]' # and filtering *those* for ones that end in spaces
  -print0              # ...delimiting output with NUL characters
)

shopt -s extglob                            # turn on extended glob syntax
while IFS= read -r -d '' source_name; do    # read NUL-separated values to source_name
  dest_name=${source_name%%+([[:space:]])}  # trim trailing whitespace from name
  mv -- "$source_name" "$dest_name"         # rename source_name to dest_name
done < <("${find_cmd[@]}")                  # w/ input from the find command defined above
```

See also:

- [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001), describing the `while read` loop's syntax in general, and the purposes of the specific amendments (`IFS=`, `read -r`, etc) above.
- [BashFAQ #100](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100), describing how to do string manipulation in bash (particularly including the `${var%suffix}` syntax, known as "parameter expansion", used to trim a suffix from a value above).
- [Using Find](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind), providing a general introduction both to the use of `find` and its integration with bash.

Comment: `mv -- "$source_name" "$dest_name"`, that's why it's always a good experience to see how Charles would do it.... You did say "*correct in corner cases*", well done.

Comment: @Charles  Thanks so much for your answer.  Following the definitions you provided, I tried to look for the directories with trailing spaces. I also created a directory with a trailing space, just to make sure everything was working properly. I used the following syntax:   **find . '*[[:space:]]' -depth -type d -print0**.  When I ran the command, I got a list of all of the directories in the disk, with no distinction of whether or not they had a trailing space and I got the following message: **'*[[:space:]]' no such file or directory**. Could you please help me to figure out what is wrong?

Comment: @Leia, it's essential to have `-name` directly before `'*[[:space:]]'` -- otherwise, it's treated as the name of a single directory to search, rather than a criterion to use for filtering. (To explain the result reported above, then: The command given in your comment was searching from *two* top-level directories: `.` as the first, `*[[:space:]]` as the second; no single directory exists by that latter name, hence the error and the unfiltered output.)

Comment: @Charles  Thank you so much for your help, I really appreciate it.  I now understand where I went wrong. I ran the correct syntax and I got a list of the directories with trailing spaces. I then tried to remove the trailing spaces using the following commands: **shopt -s extglob while IFS= read -r -d ' ' source_name; do dest_name=${source_name%%+([[:space:]])} mv -- "source_name" "$dest_name" done < <("${find_cmd[@]}")** and I got the following mistake:  **bash: syntax error near unexpected token 'do"** What does this error mean? Sorry to keep bothering you with this!

Comment: Could you clarify where the command, as you ran it, included newlines? Not having a newline been the `extglob` and the `while` could have that effect. Should also have either a newline or a semicolon before the `mv` and the `done`. There are some other possible sources of spurious errors as well -- make sure the script is saved with UNIX rather than DOS newlines.

Comment: (sorry, "been the" should have been "between the"; prior comment was posted from a phone)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.  I didn't have a newline the first time around so this time I wrote the command and saved it UNIX, however, after I ran it Linux the files still had the trailing spaces and I got no error message:
    #!/bin/bash
    shopt -s extglob                            
    while IFS= read -r -d '' source_name; do    
      dest_name=${source_name%%+([[:space:]])}  
      mv -- "$source_name" "$dest_name"         
    done < <("${find_cmd[@]}") 

I saved the file as "script" and used chmod +x /path/script and then ./script since the file was in the same directory

Comment: I don't see `find_cmd` defined (ie. actually having a value assigned) in the code in the directly-above comment -- if it's not defined, then `<("${find_cmd[@]}")` would be doing nothing, rather than actually looking for files. That said, could I ask you to post code samples as [gists](https://gist.github.com/)? That way we have comments, revision control, and the ability to see changes to a gist over time. Adding the log of `bash -x thescript` as a second file in the same gist would be helpful.

Comment: @C  Thanks so much for being so patient with me. I am sorry that I couldn’t post the code properly, but you were right: I was missing the find_cmd definition.  Once I included it in the script (https://gist.github.com/anonymous/643f92d33b9e53c8d634ee81417458b9), everything ran smoothly and the trailing spaces were finally removed from the names of the directories. I then thought that I could use this script to look for **files** in all of these directories with trailing spaces in their names.  I tried writing -type f instead of -type d but nothing happened... Why is this not working?

Comment: I actually would have expected that to work. Could you provide a log showing how running `bash -x thescript` behaves, and also the output of `find . -type f -name '*[[:space:]]' -printf '<%P>\n'`, run in the same directory? (Should be able to edit that into the gist as two separate additional files).

Comment: @C I created a test folder with a trailing space in its name. Inside it I created 3 more folders: 2 with trailing spaces and 1 without. Each folder contains 3 identical files: 1 without spaces and 2 with trailing spaces. The script I used (file_script), along with the original (directory_script) and the log (created by using the command script) are here:  https://gist.github.com/anonymous/75215602164e4f82a6c87a2df7db38ad. Since the log has many strange characters, I also include a copy of the terminal output (file.txt). Neither script worked (directory_script should have worked though).

Answer (score 3):

`find . -name "* " -type d`

`.` searches current directory and subdirectories.

`-name` searches for filenames that match (asterisk means match zero more characters, the literal space matches a space at the end of the filename)

`-type d` searches for items of type directory.

Comment: maybe add an expansion, or a link to documentation for quality and long term value..? Code only answers are frowned upon at SO. Future visits could be able to quietly learn from their post, and be able to apply this new knowledge to their own issues.

Comment: Thanks @SherylHohman and kheftel, think I was just so happy to finally get the answer myself that I did not think to explain it a bit better.